# C# Removing a List from a List

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a convenient way to remove a nested list from another list if it meets certain requirements? For example, say we have a collection of stops, and we decide to call each collection of stops a route. Each route is in list from. Then we decide to put each route into a list as well.

So now that we have a list of routes, someone decides that certain types of routes really shouldn't be included in the route list. How can I remove those routes? Here's some sample code:

Example Class

```
public class Stops
{
    public Stops(int _param1, string _param2)
    {
        param1 = _param1;
        param2 = _param2;
    }

    public int param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
}
```

Create the Lists

```
List<List<Stops>> lstRoutes = new List<List<Stops>>();
List<Stops> lstStops = new List<Stops>();
List<Stops> lstMoreStops = new List<Stops>();

// Create some stops
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    lstStops.Add(new Stops(i, "some text"));
}

lstRoutes.Add(lstStops);

// Create some more stops
for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
{
    lstMoreStops.Add(new Stops(i, "some more text"));
}

lstRoutes.Add(lstMoreStops);
```

How can I remove any route from lstRoutes that has, say, any param1 value greater than 6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way (which can be applicable to all enumerables, not just lists) would be:

```cs
lstRoutes = lstRoutes.Where(r => !r.Any(s => s.param1 > 6)).ToList();
```

The snippet above creates a new list, so copying will occur which means both the performance and memory usage will slightly suffer. The most efficient way would be not adding those items to the list in the first place.

The second most efficient way would be to remove items from the list instead of constructing a new one, so the memory usage wouldn't be affected as much:

```cs
lstRoutes.RemoveAll(r => r.Any(s => s.param1 > 6));
```

Comment: Ha I wish I could avoid adding them to the list in the first pace. Unfortunately, the starting list is a bunch of permutations and I have the task of getting rid of the permutations that don't make sense. The first bit of code you posted threw the following error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type because it is not a delegate type. BUT the second bit worked great. Thank you very much!

Comment: do you know how I could get the index of param1? I know in this case it will always be 0, but say each route consisted of a bunch of integers, and I wanted to remove all routes where 6 occurred before 7. If not, no big deal. I'lll either figure it out or start another question.

Comment: @BrentBarbata I'm sorry, I only saw your comments now. I hope you don't still need help on this after a decade :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Stops> stop = lstRoutes.Find(delegate(List<Stops> stp) { return stp.param1 > 6; });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, but I couldn't seem to get this to work. I received the following error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Stops>' does not contain a definition for 'param1' and no extension method 'param1' accepting a first argument of type 'Stops' could be found.